# Ubuntu Running an instance over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, openssl

I want to run one of my instance in AWS ubuntu over HTTPS.What is the options available for this ?

I'm using free acoount so should I purchase a SSL from amazon or I can create my own certificate and port it to my instance.

Can you tell the best procedure for the above requirement ? If I've to install the SSL,can you give me a blog post which shows ,how to install the certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon doesn't sell SSL certificates. You need to go to a vendor like GoDaddy, Namecheap, Comodo, Verisign, etc. for one. They have install instructions as part of their process.

Comment: :Can i do this ? http://jjshacks.blogspot.in/2012/05/generate-and-upload-ssl-certificate-to.html

Comment: Yes, but browsers will present a big scary warning about a self-signed certificate. It's fine for internal use but not good for a customer-facing website.